# jquery fadein duration variable from input field

Tags: jquery, fadein

I want to have the fadein duration equal to a user input value. The code below does not work. Please help. thank you

```
<button class="btn1">Fade out white</button>
<button class="btn2">Fade in black</button>
<input type='number' id='seconds' onblur="f_function()">

<script>
function f_function(){
  var num_sec = $('#seconds').val();

  $(".btn1").click(function(){
      $('#box').fadeOut(num_sec);
  });

  $(".btn2").click(function(){
      $('#box').fadeIn(num_sec);
  });
};
</script>
```

Comment: there is no box element in your code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m2p8nsuy/  You need miliseconds, and need actual/fresh value of miliseconds on click...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert value to ***`int`*** first and then convert it to ***mili-second***:-

```
var num_sec = parseInt($('#seconds').val())*1000;
```

And you have to do it like below actually:-

```
<button class="btn1">Fade out white</button>
<button class="btn2">Fade in black</button>
<input type='number' id='seconds'>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
      $('#box').fadeOut(parseInt($('#seconds').val())*1000);
  });

  $(".btn2").click(function(){
      $('#box').fadeIn(parseInt($('#seconds').val())*1000);
  });
});
</script>
```

***Example:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
      $('#box').fadeOut(parseInt($('#seconds').val())*1000);
  });

  $(".btn2").click(function(){
      $('#box').fadeIn(parseInt($('#seconds').val())*1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1">Fade out white</button>
<button class="btn2">Fade in black</button>
<input type='number' id='seconds'>

<div id="box">fill value in input box and then click on buttons to see fadeIn/fadeOut effect</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery duration is in `milliseconds`

It should be:

```
var num_sec = $('#seconds').val() * 1000;
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

You can do something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".btn1").click(function(){
  var num_sec = $('#seconds').val() ;
  if( num_sec == "" ) return; /*Return if #seeconds has no value */
                $('#box').fadeOut( num_sec * 1000 );
 });

 $(".btn2").click(function(){
  var num_sec = $('#seconds').val();
  if( num_sec == "" ) return; /*Return if #seeconds has no value */
        $('#box').fadeIn( num_sec * 1000 );
 });
});
```

```css
#box {
 width : 300px;
 height : 300px;
 background-color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1">Fade out white</button>
<button class="btn2">Fade in black</button>
<input type='number' id='seconds'>
<div id="box"></div>
```